# Map project with android V2 doesnt work

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to make google map android v2 to work. I followed all the instructions here http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html  ; got the key, add permissions,.. all the codes are same with this link. I just changed the package name and API key which i got myself.
in my mainactivity all the com.google. .. are red. The project doesnt know them. But I installed google play in my SDK. could you help me what is the problem plz

Comment: Have you signed your appliczation with the debug key or developers key? what API key have you used the debug or production key?

Comment: I dont know the difference. I simply followed the link: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html and used debug keystore if you mean this. the thing is the library is unknown for the project..

Comment: the error i get when i hover over the imports i have on my mainactivity: "The import com.google cannot be resolved"

Answer (score 1):

Go to to your project folder right click -> properties -> Android and make sure that you have selected Google Api as a target Name and not Android!

Comment: Actually in V2 it doesnt matter which you are using i could able to run it with both google API or android!

Comment: I got it. I missed step 3 and 4 of this great page: https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw